# Let $M=\{x \in l2 : x_1 -x_2=0, x_2+x_3=0\}$. Find orthogonal projection $P$ onto $M^{\perp}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M=\{x \in l2 : x_1 -x_2=0, x_2+x_3=0\}$. Find orthogonal projection $P$ onto $M^{\perp}$.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem if this were in $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $\ell^2$? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in $M$ has the form
$$
       \alpha (1,1,-1,0,0,0,\cdots)+(0,0,0,x_4,x_5,\cdots),
$$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar and $x_n, n\ge 4$ are arbitrary. It is not hard to see that $y\in M^{\perp}$ iff $y_n =0,\; n \ge 4$ and
$$
            y_1+y_2-y_3=0.
$$
So $M^{\perp}$ is the two-dimensional subspace spanned by
$$
             (1,0,1,0,0,0,\cdots), \\
             (0,1,1,0,0,0,\cdots).
$$
An equivalent orthonormal basis for $M^{\perp}$ is
$$
     \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1,0,0,0,0,\cdots),\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(1,1,2,0,0,0,\cdots)\right\}
$$
Therefore, the orthogonal projection $P$ onto $M^{\perp}$ may be written as
$$
    P(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)=\\ =\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}(1,-1,0,0,0,\cdots)+\frac{x_1+x_2+2x_3}{6}(1,1,2,0,0,0,\cdots)
$$